# props.BoolProperty's update not being called when pressed

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, properties

I am trying to do a simple floating menu toggles with update functions linked.

At the moment the update functions does not get called (not showing up in the console) which means something is not quite right.

Any idea what could be the reason?

The code is as follows (triggered with SHIFT+R):

```
import bpy

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_bool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="my_bool", update=lambda self, context: print("hello world"))

def my_menu_draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    props = context.scene.my_properties    
    layout.prop(props, "my_bool")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyProperties)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
    
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Window', space_type='EMPTY')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu', 'R', 'PRESS', shift=True)
    kmi.properties.name = "VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus"
    
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.append(my_menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyProperties)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_properties
    
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps['Window']
    km.keymap_items.remove(km.keymap_items.find('wm.call_menu', 'R', 'PRESS', shift=True))
    
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.remove(my_menu_draw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hello. Is it a typo ? You register SHIFT Q and unregister SHIFT R

Comment: @Gorgious oh yes, thanks, let me update.

Comment: The message is printing on my end. Are you running this script inside of Blender ?